# Extracting rows for a Pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have imported a simple query log into a pandas dataframe in Python (see image), and would like to know what the most efficient way is to extract all of the rows that contain any given keyword that is contained in the 'Keyword' column.

I could iterate over the dataframe - but have a feeling there might be a quicker way using arrays/masks.

Any help greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You keywords appear to be numbers (have you read in your dataframe correctly?). Also, in future please could you copy and paste the actual code of your dataframe (rather than an image) we can copy and paste it and answer your question easier...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods), for example:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([['abc', 1], ['cde', 2], ['efg', 3]])

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
     0  1
0  abc  1
1  cde  2
2  efg  3

In [3]: df[0].str.contains('c')
Out[3]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool

In [4]: df[df[0].str.contains('c')]
Out[4]:
     0  1
0  abc  1
1  cde  2
```

Comment: Thanks for this Andy, how do I cope when df[0].str.contains('c') returns NA/NaN?

Comment: Using `df[df[0].str.contains('c') == True]` should deal with NaN. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
[3]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = ['foo','bar','bah','bad','bar'],B = range(5)))

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
     A  B
0  foo  0
1  bar  1
2  bah  2
3  bad  3
4  bar  4

In [5]: select = Series(['bar','bah'])

In [6]: df[df.A.isin(select)]
Out[6]: 
     A  B
1  bar  1
2  bah  2
4  bar  4
```

Comment: Thanks for this and apologies for not pasting the table and getting the fieds misaligned - I can confirm that I imported data correctly and 'Keyword' column is indeed the one that contains the string. Your suggestion above is almost there in that it matches the whole of a cell in the keyword column - but how do I match a substring?

Comment: Andy's answer contains that solution